# How to enter underscripts in 12.2?

Tags: keyboard, compatibility, configuration

In the last version of *Mathematica* (*12.2*), some genius on Wolfram thought that is was a good idea to change the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, that have been there for years, so now users get a (broken) box to input TeX (doesn't work in my system) instead of an underscript.

It's possible, but really annoying, to enter underscripts entering an overscript (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) and switching to underscript (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>), then deleting the overscript.

This change also breaks the documentation of `Underscript`, by the way.

Is there a way to configure the notebook and remap the shortcut to the older one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *Mathematica 12.2* the way to enter underscripts is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma). At least on macOS.

Comment: Thank you! That works for me, too (in Windows 10).
I guess now i only need to fight the muscular memory from years of using ctrl-4
‍♂️

Comment: @jjagmath This is mentioned in [Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html), but WRI seems to forget to update the document page of `Underscript`…

Comment: @jjagmath Just found the document of `Underscript` has been updated, not quite sure when it happened, though.